# Editar dados NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho um Crud NodeJs onde consigo fazer inclusão de dados no banco, porém agora queria editar esses dados e o tutorial que sigo é um pouco antigo, nesse tutorial a edição é feita por `PUT` a minha pagina JADE está dessa forma:

```
extends ../layout

block content
    h1 Alteração de Usuário
    hr
    br
    form(method="POST", action="/usuarios/edit/#{value._id}", role="form")
      input(type="hidden" name="_method" value="put")
      div(class="form-group")
        label Nome:
        input(type="text", name="nome", class="form-control", value="#{value.nome}")
      div(class="form-group")
        label Login:
        input(type="text", name="login", class="form-control", value="#{value.login}")
      input(type="submit", value="Atualizar", class="btn btn-success")
    br
    br
    a(href="/usuarios" title="Voltar") Voltar
```

E esse é o meu método update que fica no controle:

```
update: function(req,res){
            Usuario.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                        var model   = data;
                        model.nome  = req.body.nome;
                        model.login = req.body.login;
                        model.save(function(err){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            }else{
                              res.redirect('/usuarios');
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        }
```

E a rota é essa:

```
app.put('/usuarios/edit/:id', usuarios.update);
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: No controller, o primeiro erro está retornando algo? Se sim, o que?

No else, já tentou logar o "model" e ver como estão preenchidos os campos? No callback, está caindo no erro ou sucesso?

Comment: Não está dando nenhum erro, quando tento editar aparece isso ná pagina: `Cannot POST /usuarios/edit/5596819e5410f3a422b5aa7c`

Comment: quando tento logar o model no else não aparece nada também.

Comment: é vazio ou não chega no ponto?

Comment: Existe um rota /usuarios/edit/:id do tipo POST?

Comment: a rota é do tipo PUT, no tutorial que sigo fala que PUT não é mais utilizado porém precisa fazer uma "gambiarra" dessa forma:
`form(method="POST", action="/usuarios/edit/#{value._id}", role="form")`
isso fica na minha pagina `edit`

Comment: Sera que se eu alterar a rota para POST funciona?

Comment: Então, no caso no seu form você está dizendo que a requisição é post: 

form(method="POST", action="/usuarios/edit/#{value._id}", role="form")

Comment: Coloquei como POST e funcionou. Obrigado por ajudar, coloque como resposta para que eu possa marcar como correta

Comment: No tutorial o cara colocava put e funcionava, acho que funcionava por ser uma versão antiga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere o método da rota para POST, para saber mais sobre http: https://speakerdeck.com/eggegg/http

[]'s

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Como você quer um PUT, você precisa do módulo [method-override](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override)

E ai sim:

```
form(method="POST", action="/usuarios/edit/#{value._id}?_method=PUT", role="form")
```

Antigamente o method-override fazia parte do express, mas na versão 4, foi separado em outro middleware. Faça dessa forma com o ?_method=PUT e instale o method-override. Dai sim, deve funcionar e você conseguir fazer o PUT.